# Seeking book about Indy using Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

I already asked a few beginner questions, found some demos, altered them and realize that I might have a lot more questions ...

- Should I use Indy 10 or 9 with Delphi 7?
- What if my server wants to broadcast something to all the clients?
- too many more to list, and I'd rather educate myself, if I can, than continually ask for help

Does anyone know of a book which covers Indy programming in Delphi (preferably D7) ?

Comment: You also have a look to ICS (IP Open source library) : http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html which is (for me), more easy to implement and with a lot of well done examples. The last version V7 is OK for D7.

Comment: Why not just ask your indivdual questions here on SO? This will also help other people having the same questions. And in my experience you'll get very high quality answers and some discussions as well.

Comment: Most people are using Indy 10, not Indy 9, these days. And I wouldn't bother with a book. just use the examples.   And check out the alternatives, like ICS, too.

Comment: Ah, happy days, back when we had a [tag:books] tag  ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling for "indy book delphi" returns "Indy in Depth" http://www.atozed.com/indy/book/index.nl.aspx as the first result. The page mentions it hasn't been updated recently, but as you are using Delphi 7 it will probably still be pertinent to you.

Answer (score 1):

Im currently using 9 with Delphi 7. No issue for me so far - mainly work with UDP/TCP servers/clients.

Indy 10 AFAIK has architectually changed under the hood, so definately pick one and stick with it. I have looked into upgrading but it seems it will require a code change for me, but i would normally advise to choose the latest version, since you will have better support.

Check the Indy homepage for more info (note i think its a bit outdated):
 [http://www.indyproject.org/download/Files/Indy10.html](http://Indy%20Project)

Here is also an article about the fundamental differences between the two:
[http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32160](http://Indy%209%20vs%2010)

Comment: +1 thanks. As Indy 10 is not stable yet I guess I will go with Indy 9.